# sql on double select without join statement

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql

i want to select all the productreview item and productimage.productimage, how to select? if i do not use double select it may show the bright entity quantity. pls help me to select the productimg and select a the item on productreview

[image]

the way i do it cant get the result i want

```
select distinct `productreview.userid,
    productreview.productid,
    productreview.producttitle,
    productreview.productreview,
    productreview.recommend,
    productreview.reviewdate,
    productreview.posted,
    productimage.productimg 
from productreview,product,productstock,productimage 
where productreview.productid=product.productid AND
    product.productid=productstock.productid and 
    productstock.productid=productimage.productid and 
    productstock.productcolortype = productimage.productcolortype and 
    productimage.productcolortype='type1'`
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. BTW have you used `JOIN`s in your queries before.

Comment: Please show us some example input and expected output for your query.

Answer (score 0):

you can join ProductReview table with ProdutImage table on basis of productID column. Here is SQL Query

```
SELECT PR.*,PI.ProductImg FROM ProdcutReview AS PR INNER JOIN ProdcutImg AS PI
ON PR.ProductID = PI.ProductID
```